# Discovering a Bluetooth HID scanner iPad 2 using External Accessory framework

Tags: ios, bluetooth, barcode-scanner, external-accessory

I'm trying to get my iPad2 app to discover a connected bluetooth scanner which is manually paired to the iPad with the External Accessory framework (I found that it is impossible for a non BT 4.0 device to discover non-connected but available devices without going through some sort of root).

It would be amazing if I could get the scanner to scan barcode data and read it through a stream to the `EAManager` instead of overriding the virtual keyboard of the iPad. I am currently using a hack by getting the read barcodes in through a hidden `UITextView` on my main view. This is extremely frustrating as the focus of the textview has to be refreshed every time something is read (Check through a '\n' char) and is prone to many glitches.

Comment: If the scanner isn't MFI compatible then you won't be able to connect to it (other than as a keyboard) without jailbreaking your device.

Comment: I don't get how is the UITextField and KeyBoard related to a Scanner... Does your device send inputs? Don't you have something in your EADSession to read inputstream?

Comment: The issue here is that the scanner will not be detected by the EAManager as it does not have a identifiable protocol (or not that I know of in my attempts to find one). The scanner I'm working with at the moment is the Motorola CS3000 and it emulates the iPad's keyboard through HID. This is is really bad as users should be able to scan products as well as use the app's searh product feature independently without having to switch text fields.